# PHP goutte screenshot

Tags: php, web-crawler, screenshot, goutte

I have a PHP goutte script that submits a couple of forms from a web page, but the next thing I want to is to take a screenshot of the page the crawler is and save it on a folder.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Goutte\Client;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;


$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://login.siat.sat.gob.mx/nidp/idff/sso?id=mat-ptsc-totp&sid=10&option=credential&sid=10');

$form = $crawler->selectButton('Enviar')->form();

$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('Ecom_User_ID' => 'xxx', 'Ecom_Password' => 'xxx'));

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.siat.sat.gob.mx/PTSC/');

echo $crawler->html();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your script?. Please read this and make the necessary changes to your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AndrewMyers but I need to do a screenshot, not downloading and image

Comment: Oops. I should have read that question more carefully. I did a [little](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/browser_kit/introduction.html) [searching](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dom_crawler.html) (Goutte is based on those libraries), but I have not seen anything to indicate that Goutte can actually render a screenshot.